# TinyMCE triggers a script that I never included: It's pretty interesting, isn't it?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, tinymce-4

Ok, beforehand I apologize for my English and theoretical mistakes, but I'm not a native speaker and neither am I a professional. I'm just a student and my level is very basic.

The problem I'm dealing with, that I consider crazy, but I can't deny is really interesting is that `TinyMCE 4 triggers` a script that I never included.

The page I'm working at has both PHP and HTML5 statements. `TinyMCE` replaces a `Textarea` and works (I mean, it appears and does its job).

I can say that it runs a script that I never included because this script adds a `md5` entry in my MySQL database. The entry is a token, it is created randomly and converted in `md5`. It is the only script that can do that. Indeed, if I edit the filename of the script, the problem still will occur, but if I edit the extension of the script (eg. from .php to .bak) no new entries are added to the database.

My last test was moving an `exit() statement` from point to point of the script until I found that the problem occurs after `</textarea>`, the `textarea` replaced by `TinyMCE`.

I've run out of ideas, don't know how to fix it and more, would be happy to share this experience and understand together with the masters (as I consider you) what is going.

Here is the relevant code (of 625 lines) I've isolated to help you figure out:

```html
     <textarea name="pagebody" id="pagebody" class="MCEeditor" cols="88" rows="16">
      Lorem ipsum...
     </textarea>
```

Here is the php script (whose relative location from the former is ../includes/footer.php)

```html
<?php
$tkn = rand(10000,getrandmax())*rand(10000,getrandmax())*rand(10000,getrandmax());
$tkn = md5($tkn);
//echo $tkn;
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$query ="INSERT INTO temporary_tokens (tokens) VALUES ('$tkn')";
mysqli_query ($myConnection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
?>
```

Hope that this may improve my question

UPDATE!!!

I've solved, but want to share with you the whole investigation process in case it may be useful to other coders

1. I temporarily changed the length of the field of temporary tokens in
   the database from VARCHAR(255) to VARCHAR(8000)  ;
2. then, temporarily
       added $tkn = print_r($_SERVER, true); in footer.php, before //echo
       $tkn; line;
3. than, ran the page which generates the problem and fetch the new entrty of the database  ;
4. and finally i found this line [REDIRECT_URL] =>    http://localhost/blogghe/administrator/css/content.css  ;

As many of you probably already know, content.css is an optional stylesheet of tinymce configuration.

Then, I went to my folder to try to whatch inside the file but can't find it because the location is wrong.

But if the location was wrong, how could tinyMCE browse to it? Then I tried to reach the page from Chrome, and the page was not found, BUT since my .htaccess contains a rewrite rule which redirects to a customized 404 page and it includes footer.php, that is the bad guy!!!

I have to admit that there were too many variables in this problem to reduce them to a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable snippet, and perhaps the idea of storing the $_SERVER array instead of the usual token was totally crazy! But I'm satisfied of my effort and happy to share this story with the community.

Comment: Then please create an [mcve]. Without code, nobody can help you.

Comment: I've done, hope this may help